# Google Sheets Dropdown Link To Go To Row Under Frozen Section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that I have some dropdown menus using chips. When I select a chip from the dropdown menu it goes to a specific cell. I have a frozen section, rows 1-5. When I click on a chip from the dropdown I would like it to go to that row and bring the row right under the frozen section. Currently it goes to the row but keeps it at the bottom of the page.

Here is a sample Google Sheet I created.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19YGRQ3FBI8LTUPjqyD5lyhEn4rHQNe2Ujd-kBvYB-6g/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script I use for going to the specific cell after selecting the chip. Is there something I can add to this to make it go to the line right under the frozen section?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() != 'Sheet25') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 2 && e.range.rowStart != 1) return;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet25');
  switch (e.value) {
    case ('Test 1'): sheet.getRange('a6').activate(); break;
    case ('Test 2'): sheet.getRange('a35').activate(); break;
    case ('Test 3'): sheet.getRange('a85').activate(); break;
    case ('Test 4'): sheet.getRange('a105').activate(); break;
  }   
}
```

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In order to search for a value of the dropdown list from column "A", I used TextFinder.
- In this case, before the searched cell is activated, the bottom cell is activated. By this, when the searched cell is activated, the cell is moved just under the frozen rows.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. Before you use this script, please confirm whether the same function names are not existing. This is an important point.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Sheet25') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 2 && e.range.rowStart != 1) return;
  var r = sheet.getRange(`A${sheet.getFrozenRows() + 1}:A${sheet.getLastRow()}`).createTextFinder(e.value).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (!r) return;
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  r.activate();
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used in your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your provided Spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))